# Keeping a scrubber on one device in sync with a video playing on another

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit, avplayer

I have two iOS devices, and both have a copy of the same video. Both devices are communicating over bluetooth. The video is only playing on one device while the other is the remote control. The "remote control" device needs a scrubber showing where in the duration the video is.

What is the best way to keep the scrubber in sync with the video playing?

I'm using AVPlayer for playing the video and Gamekit for the bluetooth connection.

Comment: Get the player device to send the current location maximum. Update the scrubber based on time taken, and use the current location to adjust the scrubber location. Then, all you need to do is respond to stops, pauses, restarts etc. How fined grained do you want the control to be, should the scrubber control the video playback position as well, or should it just indicate location?

Comment: It needs to indicate the location and also be controlled. The device playing the video has no control. The "remote control" device would start/stop the video. The problem I'm not quite sure about is the network latency - by the time the remote control device says play there is the time to receive the message and the time to actually start playing. I need the user to not notice any discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh, well that will be fun to get working. Latency is something you will always get, so you need some mitigation strategies. I would suggest looking at certain ways that people deal with lag. One thing i can suggest is dividing your two message types into critical and non critical. so for example, a stop/pause/play/restart command would to me, be critical. You want that message to get through, and you will keep trying till it does.

Messages such as changing the scrubber position, in both directions (player to remote, remote to player), are non critical. You are sending them, but you shouldn't waste time acking the responses or making sure they are delivered. Sort of similar to the difference between UDP and TCP. These will just be sent over the connection, and i would basically have the package being no more complicated than (scrubberposition, position_as_time, identifier_number ). Record the last identifier number you got (identifier number is a monotonically increasing number) and discard any messages with numbers below this, and update to the position for any higher numbers, and update your stored identifier_number.

I hope this makes sense/helps, let me know if i need to explain anything further, and good luck

Comment: Should I be using addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval on the player side and send UDP message for each update, or should I be using an NSTimer on the remote side to simulate the slider moving and possibly make small corrections? When using addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval I think there were about 1000 messages for a 5 second video.

Comment: You prob don't need to send that many messages. People arent going to be able to tell the difference between the scrubber moving from 50 updates in 5 seconds, let alone 1000. You will probably have to experiment on what is the nicest way of doing it. My one word would be, don't allow the scrubber to move backwards unless rewinding is on. People will not notice if the scrubber slows down/pauses every so often, but they will notice if it goes backwards when it shouldn't. your solution will have to use a combination of the two. Also, bluetooth uses power, so limiting the messages is a good idea.

Comment: I just realized that you're able to customize the interval of addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval. I was looking at AVPlayerDemo. The sample code adjusts the interval according to the width of the slider and the length of the video. The longer the video, the longer the interval. It seems that with shorter videos you get more frequent intervals. I just did MAX(0.25f, interval), for example. Further testing will show what the value should be.

Comment: ah, good to know. Glad you're getting some results with it :)